# Export selected node and edge in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

is there a way that I can export selected node and edge from graph and display the selected ones in another graph. maxkfranz said that we can export as json. Do you have any idea how I can do that？ Thanks。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried something along the lines of:

`cy.$(':selected').json()`

Edit : The API now also allows for multiple elements, e.g. `cy.$(':selected').jsons()`

Comment: Of course, this would only work for one element since `ele.json()` returns a single object for one element, but you could iterate over the collection and call `ele.json()` for each one, appending to an array or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I get the output of (var json=cy.$(':selected').json())below:Object {data: Object, position: Object, group: "nodes", bypass: undefined, removed: false…}, but when I use cy.load(json), it doesn't work at all. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: You just got the element JSON.  You still need a proper graph JSON for cy.load()