# cytoscape.js show selected nodes and edges in new graph on right-click

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have a graph ([source credit](http://blog.js.cytoscape.org/public/demos/getting-started/index-layout.html)) where I can select a (or multiple) node(s) and its connected edges (the edges turn blue when I select a node). Now, how do I have to go about if I wanted to show a new graph consisting of the selected nodes and edges when right-clicking on one of the already selected nodes?

Here's what I've done so far:

`cytoscape.js` from [here](http://view-source:http://blog.js.cytoscape.org/public/demos/getting-started/cytoscape.js)

`index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- source: http://blog.js.cytoscape.org/public/demos/getting-started/index-layout.html -->

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <title>Tutorial 1: Getting Started</title>
    <script src="cytoscape.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    #cy {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="cy"></div>
    <script>
        var cy = cytoscape({
          container: document.getElementById('cy'),
          elements: [
            // nodes
            { data: { id: 'a' } },
            { data: { id: 'b' } },
            { data: { id: 'c' } },
            { data: { id: 'd' } },
            { data: { id: 'e' } },
            { data: { id: 'f' } },
            // edges
            {
              data: {
                id: 'ab',
                source: 'a',
                target: 'b'
              }
            },
            {
              data: {
                id: 'cd',
                source: 'c',
                target: 'd'
              }
            },
            {
              data: {
                id: 'ef',
                source: 'e',
                target: 'f'
              }
            },
            {
              data: {
                id: 'ac',
                source: 'a',
                target: 'c'
              }
            },
            {
              data: {
                id: 'be',
                source: 'b',
                target: 'e'
              }
            }
          ],
          style: [
            {
              selector: 'node',
              style: {
                shape: 'vee',
                'background-color': '#A60059',
                label: 'data(id)'
              }
            }],

          layout: {
            name: 'grid'
          }
        });


        cy.on('select', 'node', function(evt){
          evt.cyTarget.connectedEdges().animate({
          style: { lineColor: 'blue' }
          });
        });

       /* cy.on('cxttap', 'node', function(evt) {
        evt.cyTarget.connectedEdges().animate({
        style: {lineColor: 'green'}
        });
        });*/

    </script>
</body>
```

The commented `cy.on('cxttap','node', function()...)` shows the event handling to turn the edges into green color when right-clicking on a node. But, how do I get (i.e. load) all the previously selected nodes and edges into a new graph (and display it)? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620146/export-selected-node-and-edge-in-cytoscape-js) post, which says that one has to use sth like:

`cy.$(':selected').jsons()`

But honestly, I am a bit lost in how to do that. Any help would be very appreciated.

**EDIT:**

OK, so with the hint of maxkfranz, I was able to get the selected nodes (and their edges) to another graph `cy2`. So, when I select multiple nodes (`ctrl+drag-selector-over-nodes) and then right-click on one of the selected nodes, they get drawn to a new graph in another div. Here is my updated code (data now gets loaded from an external json file):

**testdata.json**:

```
{ "nodes" : [
      {"data": {"id": "a"}},
      {"data": {"id": "b"}},
      {"data": {"id": "c"}},
      {"data": {"id": "d"}},
      {"data": {"id": "e"}},
      {"data": {"id": "f"}}
    ],

  "edges" : [
      {
      "data": {
      "id": "ab",
      "source": "a",
      "target": "b"
      }
      },
      {
      "data": {
      "id": "cd",
      "source": "c",
      "target": "d"
      }
      },
      {
      "data": {
      "id": "ef",
      "source": "e",
      "target": "f"
      }
      },
      {
      "data": {
      "id": "ac",
      "source": "a",
      "target": "c"
      }
      },
      {
      "data": {
      "id": "be",
      "source": "b",
      "target": "e"
      }
      }
    ]

}
```

**index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- source: http://blog.js.cytoscape.org/public/demos/getting-started/index-layout.html -->

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <title>Tutorial 1: Getting Started</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cytoscape.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    #cy {
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }

    #cy2 {
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="cy"></div>
    <div id="cy2"></div>
    <script>
        var cy2 = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy2'),
          style: [
            {
              selector: 'node',
              style: {
                shape: 'vee',
                'background-color': '#A60059',
                label: 'data(id)'
              }
            }],

          layout: {
            name: 'grid'
          }

       });

        $.getJSON("testdata.json", function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            var cy = cytoscape({
                container: document.getElementById('cy'),
                elements: data,
                style: [
            {
              selector: 'node',
              style: {
                shape: 'vee',
                'background-color': '#A60059',
                label: 'data(id)'
              }
            }],

          layout: {
            name: 'grid'
          }
            });

        cy.on('select', 'node', function(evt){
          evt.cyTarget.connectedEdges().animate({
          style: { lineColor: 'blue' }
          });
          evt.cyTarget.nodes().animate({
            style: {'background-color': 'yellow'}
        });
        });

        cy.on('cxttap', 'node', function(evt) {
        var newData = cy.$(':selected');
        console.log(newData);
        cy2.add(newData.jsons());
        });

       console.log(cy.$('node:selected'));    
       });

    </script>
</body>
```

The problem now is that this works as expected for the simultaneously selected nodes and their egdes. However, if I e.g. first select nodes `c` and `d` and then, in a next step, select node `a`, when clicking on node `a` the new graph `cy2` will only contain this single node, without the other previously selected nodes. Now I am thinking that I could e.g. select all the nodes that have the background-color yellow with their edges (this should then, principally, return all the once selected nodes). But the problem is that I don't know how to do that. Something like

`cy.$('background-color:yellow')`

doesn't work.

Again, any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
cy2.add( copy( elementsOfInterest.jsons() ) );

// where copy deep copies json, e.g. obj => _.cloneDeep(obj) or obj => JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(obj) )
```

See the docs: http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/object-ownership

> When passing objects to Cytoscape.js for creating elements, animations, layouts, etc., the objects are considered owned by Cytoscape. Objects like elements have several levels to them, and doing deep copies of those objects every time they are passed to Cytoscape creates additional expense. When desired, the dev can copy objects manually before passing them to Cytoscape. However, copying is not necessary for most developers most of the time.

You can't have two owners for one object.

Comment: Please add some explanation of how/why this solves OP's issue so that the problem is understood and resolved rather than simply fixed